# sonarqube 6.6 upgrade : Unrecoverable indexation failures

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

After sonarqube 6.6 upgrade from 6.5 (with Debian package), sonar is unable to start. I did not update plugins before upgrade. I just let the standard Debian package upgrade. I am using an external database (Postgresql).
I found the following errors in web.log :

```
    2017.10.24 18:12:34 ERROR web[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] index [components], type [component], id [AVgpp1_-x6lKXwnU0BYQ], message [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't specify parent if no parent field has been configured]
    2017.10.24 18:12:34 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.Platform] Background initialization failed. Stopping SonarQube
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unrecoverable indexation failures
            at org.sonar.server.es.IndexingListener$1.onFinish(IndexingListener.java:39)
            at org.sonar.server.es.BulkIndexer.stop(BulkIndexer.java:117)
            at org.sonar.server.component.index.ComponentIndexer.doIndexByProjectUuid(ComponentIndexer.java:149)
            at org.sonar.server.component.index.ComponentIndexer.indexOnStartup(ComponentIndexer.java:71)
            at org.sonar.server.es.IndexerStartupTask.indexUninitializedTypes(IndexerStartupTask.java:68)
            at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
            at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
            at org.sonar.server.es.IndexerStartupTask.execute(IndexerStartupTask.java:55)
            at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:159)
            at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevelStartup$1.doPrivileged(PlatformLevelStartup.java:91)
            at org.sonar.server.user.DoPrivileged.execute(DoPrivileged.java:45)
            at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevelStartup.start(PlatformLevelStartup.java:87)
            at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.executeStartupTasks(Platform.java:196)
            at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.access$400(Platform.java:46)
            at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform$1.lambda$doRun$1(Platform.java:121)
            at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform$AutoStarterRunnable.runIfNotAborted(Platform.java:371)
            at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform$1.doRun(Platform.java:121)
            at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform$AutoStarterRunnable.run(Platform.java:355)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any clue or workaround ?

Comment: The only supported solution is restoring a backup. Could you tell us from what version did you start the update? Did you update all plugins before updating?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to overcome this error by attempting another upgrade (after restoring sonar 6.5) and :

- upgrading plugins BEFORE upgrade
- removing the data/es5 folder after
  encountering the same error and restarting sonar.