# Background initialization failed. Stopping SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I am updating the sonarqube (5.6.3 > 6.7.1) and the following error is occurring:

```
2018.02.01 20:37:21 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.Platform] Background initialization failed. Stopping SonarQube
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unrecoverable indexation failures
        at org.sonar.server.es.IndexingListener$1.onFinish(IndexingListener.java:39)
        at org.sonar.server.es.BulkIndexer.stop(BulkIndexer.java:117)
        at org.sonar.server.issue.index.IssueIndexer.doIndex(IssueIndexer.java:247)
        at org.sonar.server.issue.index.IssueIndexer.indexOnStartup(IssueIndexer.java:95)
        at org.sonar.server.es.IndexerStartupTask.indexUninitializedTypes(IndexerStartupTask.java:68)
        at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
        at org.sonar.server.es.IndexerStartupTask.execute(IndexerStartupTask.java:55)
        at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:159)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevelStartup$1.doPrivileged(PlatformLevelStartup.java:84)
        at org.sonar.server.user.DoPrivileged.execute(DoPrivileged.java:45)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevelStartup.start(PlatformLevelStartup.java:80)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.executeStartupTasks(Platform.java:196)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.access$400(Platform.java:46)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform$1.lambda$doRun$1(Platform.java:121)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform$AutoStarterRunnable.runIfNotAborted(Platform.java:371)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform$1.doRun(Platform.java:121)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform$AutoStarterRunnable.run(Platform.java:355)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2018.02.01 20:37:21 DEBUG web[][o.s.s.p.Platform] Background initialization of SonarQube done
2018.02.01 20:37:22 INFO  web[][o.s.p.StopWatcher] Stopping process
```

We tried to delete the */data/es5* folder, but with no result. Any idea?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46915947/sonarqube-6-6-upgrade-unrecoverable-indexation-failures) SO question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sonarqube upgrade to 6.7: Unrecoverable indexation failures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48317780/sonarqube-upgrade-to-6-7-unrecoverable-indexation-failures)